# Running time of nested for loop

Tags: c++

Running time for following alorithm

```
int b = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < i * n; j++)   
        b = b + 5;
```

I know that the first loop is **O(n)** but that's about as far as I've gotten. I think that the second loop may be **O(n^2)** but the more I think about it the less sense it makes. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Calculate it by hand for various small values of `n`. Or add a counter and increment it inside the second `for` loop..

Answer (score 1):

We want to express the running time of this code as a function of n. Call this `T(n)`.

We can say that `T(n) = U(0,n) + U(1,n) + ... + U(n-1,n)`, where `U(i,n)` is the running time of the inner loop as a function of `i` and `n`.

The inner loop will run `i * n` times. So `U(i,n)` is just `i * n`.

So we get that `T(n) = 0*n + 1*n + 2*n + ... + (n-1)*n = n * (1 + 2 + ... + (n-1))`.

The closed form for `(1 + 2 + ... + (n-1))` is just `(n^2 - n)/2` http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+2+%2B+...+%2B+(n-1) .

So we get that `T(n) = n * (1 + 2 + ... + (n-1)) = n * ((n^2 - n)/2) = (n^3 - n^2) / 2`,

which is `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
easiest way would be to use a example

assume n=10 

1st for loop runs 10 times o(n)
2nd loop loop runs 0 if i=0
                   10 time for i=1
                   20 times for i=2
                   30 times for i=3
....  100 times(for i=10) o(n^2)

hope it helps you
```

Answer (score 1):

Outer loop runs for `n` iterations.

When `n` is 0, inner loop executes `0*n` = `0` times
When `n` is 1, inner loop executes `1*n` = `n` times
When `n` is 2, inner loop executes `2*n` = `2n` times
When `n` is 3, inner loop executes `3*n` = `3n` times
... 
...
When `n` is n, inner loop executes `n*n` = `n*n` times

So it looks like inner loop executes a total of:

```
0 + n + 2n + 3n + ... + n*n
```

Multiply this with outer loop's `n` and you get approx. a `O(n^3)` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Statements                                     Iterations
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)           |       n+1
    for (j = 0; j < i * n; j++)   |       0+n+2n+3n...n*n = n*n(n+1)/2
        b = b + 5;                |       n*n(n+1)/2
```

So overall: O(n<sup>3</sup>)

Comment: why for Ist loop it is only n? according to me is should be n+1

Comment: @user2843556 yeah, plus similarly for others too, but overall as you can see is n cube only

Comment: In n*n(n+1)/2 could u plz explain /2 ?

Comment: @user2843556 take n out as common you get `n(1+2+3...n)` =n*(sum of all numbers from 1 to n). Sum of all 1 to n if `n(n+1)/2`. They are in AP (arithmetic progression). Google this standard answer.

Comment: @user2843556 [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)